# New line in variable

Tags: shell-script, shell

I want to create a config file with a .sh file.
I can't figure out how i insert new lines.

The code i already have:

```
domainconf='<VirtualHost *:80>\n ServerName '$fulldomain'\n DocumentRoot '$fullpath'\n </VirtualHost>'
echo $domainconf > /etc/apache2/sites-available/"$fulldomain".conf
```

Comment: Hugely important to quote your variables. Please read https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/4667

Answer (score 5):

If all you need to do is to write the configuration to a file, then the following would be more readable, and it does away with the need for a variable:

```
cat >/etc/apache2/sites-available/"$fulldomain".conf <<END_CONFIG
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName '$fulldomain'
DocumentRoot '$fullpath'
</VirtualHost>
END_CONFIG
```

If you absolutely need the thing in a variable:

```
conf=$(cat <<END_CONFIG
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName '$fulldomain'
DocumentRoot '$fullpath'
</VirtualHost>
END_CONFIG
)

echo "$conf" >/etc/apache2/sites-available/"$fulldomain".conf
```

Comment: Does command substitution need double quoting?

Comment: @Kevin You may quote the command substitution if you wish, but it's not necessary here (because here-document). The important bit is the quoting of `$conf` in `echo "$conf"`.

Comment: @Kevin I'm actually unsure about it, but since I can't seem to get it to *fail* without quoting (for various odd here-doc contents), I believe it's safe. Please feel free to prove me wrong.

Comment: @Kevin not when it is the value in an assignment, although otherwise it usually does. Kusalananda: Try `echo $( cat <<STR eol lines eol STR eol )` to see the failure case.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just echo with '-e' flag

```
domainconf='<VirtualHost *:80>\n ServerName '$fulldomain'\n DocumentRoot '$fullpath'\n </VirtualHost>'
echo -e "$domainconf" > /etc/apache2/sites-available/"$fulldomain".conf
```

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux @Patrick! If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to embed literal newlines in the script:

```
% cat newl  
blah='x
y
z'

echo "$blah"
% sh newl 
x
y
z
%
```

Do note the quotes on `$blah`!

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace `echo` by `printf`

```
domainconf='<VirtualHost *:80>\n ServerName '$fulldomain'\n DocumentRoot '$fullpath'\n </VirtualHost>'
printf "$domainconf" > /etc/apache2/sites-available/"$fulldomain".conf
```

Comment: `printf` is a pretty good solution, but not the way you've used it (which is no better than `echo`).  Try `domfmt='<VirtualHost *:80>\n ServerName %s\n DocumentRoot %s\n </VirtualHost>'` followed by `printf "$domfmt" "$fulldomain" "$fullpath" > "/etc/apache2/sites-available/$fulldomain.conf"`